# Beaglebone Black emmc gpio

Tags: beagleboneblack, gpio

I have the BEAGLEBONE black, A5C.
I am having problems changing the mode pin.
I'm trying to change the way different pins but the pins P8_6 P8_03 to this mode 1 and I do not get to change mode 7

anyone can help me?

Comment: Can you post the device tree overlay file you are using to change the mode?

Comment: No deja por este metodo, ya los esta usando la beaglebone y no me deja usarlos como gpio

Comment: several gpio will not let me configure

Answer (score -1):

this [link](http://kilobaser.com/blog/2014-07-28-beaglebone-black-devicetreeoverlay-generator#dtogenerator) is you looking for. this sit can generate source dtc file in witch you can select mode of the pin.
also try [this](https://github.com/AbhraneelBera/wiringBone) if you are working on beaglebone, by far this best for beaglebone.